# How to get image from a clipped region(rotated rectangular area) in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Please refer the image attached below.

[image]

I have created a clip on canvas so that if the user paints the whole canvas only the region is get painted with red color. As you can see an area in the shape of rectangular is fully filled in meaning the clip area is fully filled in. This area need not be fully filled in.

Now I want to get the clipped area(the rotated rectangular area shown in red color with opacity 0.5) from canvas as an image so that I can write it into an offCanvas at a different desired angle. I hope I explained well.

Please refer the clipping code below if its of any help.

```
ctxOff.rotate(angle * Math.PI/180);
ctxOff.beginPath();
ctxOff.rect(-imgRectWidth/2, -imgRectHeight/2, slideImageRectNoRotate.width, slideImageRectNoRotate.height);
ctxOff.stroke();
ctxOff.restore();
ctxOff.save();
ctxOff.clip(); //Clipped region at an angle
```

Comment: You would need to create a new canvas of target size, apply inverse rotation/translation, then draw from the clipped canvas into the new canvas and save out.

Comment: I didn't get the point >> draw from the clipped canvas<<

Comment: dstContext.drawImage(srcCanvas, x, y, w, h) after the inverse transforms has been applied at dstContext.

Comment: Got it. But I think this is a bit more complicated in my case. In the above code ctxOff is the off canvas context. After each fill the off canvas is written back to the respective visible canvas using drawImage. This means the original visible canvas's context has no transforms applied. And on request I need to write back what is present in the visible canvas back to off canvas at a different angle. This is why I thought if there is a way to get an exact image from the clipped area things will be a bit easier. Hope I am clear.

Comment: I've got a clue from your answer. Forgot my previous comment for now.